# Enter vs Escape when renaming identifiers in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I'm quite new to Eclipse (transferring from NetBeans) and have noticed that the standard refactoring procedure (invoked by the default shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) for renaming identifiers in Eclipse has two modes of operation.

When I finish typing a new name for a local variable, field or method, the result is already seen on screen and I can simply press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to confirm it. In that way, the renaming goes faster (just like it was in NetBeans). However, an on-screen hint in Eclipse suggests that I should hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to confirm the operation. This way, the renaming goes somewhat longer and something is going on behind the scenes, but the only visible difference is the message *"Checking preconditionals...:"* quickly arising and disappearing at the left of the status bar.

So what is the difference between these modes of renaming and is it safe to always use <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When editing text with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> you can see all references in the class updating live. Hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> will still keep these changes however it will not save the file automatically and won't update any references mentioned in other classes.

If you then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *and* you have references in other classes errors will appear there (*xxx cannot be resolved or is not a field*)

---

<kbd>Enter</kbd> however will update all references in other classes and save the file in which you're refractoring.

Comment: It seems that when renaming method parameters and local variables, hitting Enter doesn't save the file either (maybe because such kind of renaming doesn't affect other files). But I've got your idea, thanks.

Comment: @JohnMcClane Interesting, I noticed that after Enter it does save when it's already saved, if it's not saved it will not save. That might have been what you've seen

Answer (score 3):

With ESC key, variables in the current file will be renamed.
Whereas with ENTER, references to variables in other files will also be updated.